# fluent-ffmpeg Error: Only one input stream is supported

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I am working with node, JS and express, and I am trying to merge/join multiple mp4 videos that I am fetching from AWS S3. However, when I try to merge the videos, I get the error saying:

`Error: Only one input stream is supported`
`at proto.mergeAdd.proto.addInput.proto.input`

I don't know what may be causing the error, but can someone please help me solve this?

This is my code:

```
    {/** fetching videos from AWS, S3, and calling the function */}
const videoBuffers =  videos?.map(async (video) => {
      const params = {
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: video?.Key,
        Expires: 604800,
      };

      const response = await s3Client.send(new GetObjectCommand(params));
        // returns an array of buffers
      return response.Body;
    })



await mergeVideos(videos);



async function mergeVideos(videoBuffers) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const mergedVideoPath = 'mergedVideo.mp4';

    const ffmpegInstance = ffmpeg();

    videoBuffers.forEach((videoBuffer, index) => {
      ffmpegInstance.input(videoBuffer);
    });

    const complexFilter = [];
    videoBuffers.forEach((_, index) => {
      complexFilter.push(`[${index}:v]`);
    });
    complexFilter.push(`concat=n=${videoBuffers.length}:v=1:a=0[outv]`);
    complexFilter.push(`amix=inputs=2`);

    ffmpegInstance
      .complexFilter(complexFilter, 'outv')
      .on('error', (error) => {
        console.error('Error merging videos:', error);
        reject(error);
      })
      .on('end', () => {
        console.log('Videos merged successfully');
        resolve(mergedVideoPath);
      })
      .outputOptions('-map', '[outv]')
      .output(mergedVideoPath)
      .run();
  });
}
```